# Integrating LaTeX parser in c#

Tags: c#, parsing, tex

I'm trying to make an editor that uses a LaTeX parser in C# like in here: [Online Parser](https://www.writelatex.com/32492rqtrzj)

I'm using two simple RichTextBoxs, one for writing in it, and one for showing the parsed text in.

I would like to parse the code in real time but I don't know whether I need libraries or something else to achieve this.
I don't need nor do I want to write a parser myself. I want to use something already built.

So, is there something I could use, like sending text to a parser and then receiving from it the already parsed result?

Comment: Most (as far as I know, all, actually) existing LaTeX editors with a live preview function need a TeX system installed, use that to write  to a file, and then simply display the file (which will be an image or a PDF file). Have you considered that approach?

Comment: To tell the truth I didn't thought of it...Now I will consider it thoroughly

Comment: I have dome something similar using a Google API, but it always failed to render the `+` for some reason.